# C++ How to create subclass in class with array

Tags: c++

C++ How to create subclass in class with array

Hi guys, i still learning C++ and face some issues here.

Basically i got a parent class

lets call this parent class as

```
Vehicle
```

It got 2 sub class, lets assume they are

`Car and Motorcycle`

I will create a vehicle object assume vehicle size is 20

```
Vehicle veh[20]
```

I will do the following

```
string vType;

cout << "Please enter your vehicle Type:";
cin >> vType;
```

so i do a comparision if (vType=="Car")

it will return 4 wheels from the sub class, but how do i declare its 4 wheels at Car and 2 wheels at Motorcycle , i know i need create 2 additional cpp file which is

```
class Car : public Vehicle
{
private:
int noOfWheels;
public:
computePrice();
}
```

But how do i set noOfWheels specially to Car as 4 and Motorcycle as 2.

The next is the tricky part.. after knowing how many wheel it is

i will need store a array for each wheel

```
string wheel[4];
```

since i know there 4 wheel in cars.

How do i prompt 4 type and store it in an array, and all of this in an object call Vehicle.

I can use a for loop and thats not the issue, the part i am stuck on is how do i create a string array and store the 4 prompt and then into this Vehicle[0]

```
wheel 1:
wheel 2:
wheel 3:
wheel 4:
```

When user want to print data it will be

```
Vehicle[0]
Type: Car
Wheel: 4
Wheel[0] = Fine condition
Wheel[1] = Need to check again
Wheel[2] = Fine condition
Wheel[3] = Might need get repair
```

**Thanks for all help.**

Comment: You're asking how to do object-oriented programming. I suggest studying.

Comment: i still learning.. through trial and error.

Comment: I don't see any trial above. You say you're still learning ... that was exactly my point; the way to learn is to **study**. It's sad that so many people who come to SO have no clue about how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the declaration for your array is wrong. Since you are dealing with polymorphic classes you need to use pointers.

```
Vehicle* veh[20];
```

Otherwise you will have what is called *object slicing*. Which means that even if you create a `Car` or a `Motorcycle` they will be converted into `Vehicle`s when you assign them to your array.

'how do i set noOfWheels specially to Car as 4 and Motorcycle as 2.'

In the constructor

```
class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
    Car() : noOfWheels(4) { ... }
private:
    int noOfWheels;
    ...
};

class Motorcycle : public Vehicle
{
public:
    Motorcycle() : noOfWheels(2) { ... }
private:
    int noOfWheels;
    ...
};
```

But personally I don't think you need a noOfWheels data member at all. Since the number of wheels is fixed for each type of Vehicle it's a waste of space, instead you need a virtual function

```
class  Vehicle
{
public:
    virtual int noOfWheels() const = 0;
    ...
};

class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
    virtual int noOfWheels() const { return 4; }
    ...
};

class Motorcycle  : public Vehicle
{
public:
    virtual int noOfWheels() const { return 2; }
    ...
};
```

'how do i create a string array and store the 4 prompt and then into this Vehicle[0]'

Again I would use the constructor to initialize the car wheel names.

```
class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
    Car(const std::string* w)
    { wheel[0] = w[0]; wheel[1] = w[1]; wheel[2] = w[2]; wheel[3] = w[3]; }
    virtual int noOfWheels() const { return 4; }
private:
    std::string wheel[4];
    ...
};
```

Use constructors to initialize classes. That's what they are for.

Comment: I have a question, i did what you mention and it work fine, but how do i get number of wheels at my main.cpp , after create Vehicle veh[20], how do i get car number of wheels.

Comment: As I said you need `Vehicle* veh[20];`. Nothing is going to work unless you do that. Then if you used my virtual method code you would write `veh[i]->noOfWheels()`.

Comment: sorry i did Vehicle* , typo issue.

Comment: if i did veh[i]->noOfWheels , but i want it return car noOfWheels, how do i do it?

Comment: It will return car noOfWheels that's how virtual functions work. Maybe you need to post a new question with your new code.

Comment: Hmm okay the part i am confuse is basically i will cout " Please enter vehicle type " , then i cin the result. then base on the result, lets say the result=="Car" it will cout Car noOfWheels and if the result is MotorCycle it will cout Motorcycle noOfWheels, how do i make it work this way.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the answer has been accepted, but I typed it all so I will post it all. It's a run down of OOP I guess.

Lets assume that all vehicles have wheels. All those wheels have a condition. Some vehicle have more or less wheels than others.

You need to separate the **common** aspects of the classes into higher orders, into base classes.

You also need to organize your classes to compose themselves with other classes to build a whole.

Here we have a wheel class, it has a `condition`, which is a string. You can query it's condition at any time.

```
class Wheel 
{
  public:
    const std::string GetCondition() const { return mCondition; }
  private:
    std::string mCondition;
};
```

We know that a vehicle is going to have wheels, so we store the wheels container here, to share out among the child classes through **inheritance**.

```
class Vehicle
{
  public:
    Vehicle(unsigned int wheelCount) { mWheels.resize(wheelCount, Wheel()); }
    virtual unsigned int GetWheelCount() { return mWheels.size(); }
    virtual const std::string GetWheelCondition(int wheelNumber)
    {
      return mWheels[wheelNumber].GetCondition();
    }
  protected:
    std::vector<Wheel> mWheels; // All vehicles have wheels.
};
```

A car is a *type* of `Vehicle`. Therefore it **inherits** from `Vehicle`. It has inherited a member that holds `Wheel` objects. It has also inherited methods that help to *find the wheel count* and to *get the status of a wheel by index.* This is the level that you can specialize you classes. The `Car` and `Motorbike` class both have wheels, and they have the same core functionality. We can specialize the class by adding or overloading a method.

```
class Car : public Vehicle
{
  public:
    Car() Vehicle(4) {}
    Car(unsigned int wheelCount) : Vehicle(wheelCount) {}
}

class Motorbike : public Vehicle
{
  public:
    MotorBike(unsigned int wheelCount) : Vehicle(wheelCount) {}
    void DoWheelie() { throw; }
}
```

We can use these object like so,

```
Car car(4); // Car with 4 wheels. specialized constructor.
Car standardCar(); // Car with 4 wheels, as default constructor.
Car uberCar(42); // Car with 42 wheels.    
Motorbike bike(2); // Bike with 2 wheels.
Motorbike badBike(); // No default constructor defined! Will not compile!

car.GetWheelCount(); // 4
bike.GetWheelCount(); // 2

bike.DoWheelie(); // All good.
car.DoWheelie(); // NOPE! Method doesn't exist for this.
```

There is more to say on the benefits of polymorphism and heap allocation, but I think I'll leave it here. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: I would like use your following code but i am trying to instead of create Car car, i would just want create Vehicle object ,whileas Vehicle class got private: Car carObj MotorCycle mcObj

Comment: Ok, but you should think about it like this. A _Car **is** a Vehicle_. A _Motorbike **is** a Vehicle_. It doesn't make sense that a _Vehicle **is made of** a Car and a Motorbike_.